# Child check in Database firebase not working correctly - Java

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Everything seems to be correct, but it does not work correctly. It says that the alias is busy even when it is not busy. It checks "players", it doesn't get to the name in it.

[image]

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("players/" + playerName);
rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            Name.setError("This alias is already taken");
        } else {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        
    }

});
```

Comment: What's the value of `playerName` inside the reference? And why do you say it is not busy? The `biron` fields hold a value, an empty string.

Comment: Step 1 is to stop ignoring errors and implement `onCancelled`. At its minimum that should be `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`. Step 2 is to set a breakpoint on each line of code you shared, run in the debugger, and check the value of each variable on each line. When doing this: what is the first variable that doesn't have the value you expect?

Comment: @AlexMamo `String playerName = "";`